# How to you initialize a qubit into a magic state in IBM Quantum composer

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, magic-states

I want to build/prepare a qubit transforming from $\vert 0 \rangle$ into a magic state. How do I do that?
the particular magic state I have in mind is the following,

$$ |\varphi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}|1\rangle)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a Hadamard gate to create the superposition
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$$
If you write down what you want next, you will find that you need to act with the unitary gate with matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&e^{i\pi/4}\end{pmatrix}$$
which is exactly the $P$ gate with argument $\frac{\pi}{4}$. So your circuit will look something like this:

[image]

Alternatively, you could use Qiskit with `initialize` function and then decompose the resulting circuit until you get something that can be implemented with gates in the composer. The $P$ gate is also equivalent (up to a global phase) to the $R_z$ gate so you could also use that one.